Не получается вывести уведомление через win10toast после pyinstaller
Пытался сделать уведомление через винду, в PyCharm все работает, а после билда, уведы не приходят. Можете подсказать, пожалуйста, как правильно забилдить, чтобы он отправлял уведы?
import re
import tkinter as tk
from win10toast import ToastNotifier


def parse_time_input(input_string):
    numbers = re.findall(r'\d+', input_string)
    numbers = [int(num) for num in numbers]

    if "час" in input_string:
        hours = numbers[0]
        if len(numbers) > 1:
            minutes = numbers[1]
        else:
            minutes = 0
    else:
        hours = 0
        minutes = numbers[0]

    return hours * 3600 + minutes * 60


def show_notification(message, duration=10):
    try:
        toast = ToastNotifier()
        toast.show_toast('Уведомление', message, duration=duration)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Ошибка: {e}")


def on_submit():
    street = message_entry.get()
    time_input = time_entry.get()

    total_seconds = parse_time_input(time_input)

    root.withdraw()

    def show_notification_delayed():
        show_notification(street)
        root.destroy()

    root.after(total_seconds * 1000, show_notification_delayed)


root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Уведомления')

message_label = tk.Label(root, text='Введите сообщение для уведомления:')
message_label.pack()
message_entry = tk.Entry(root)
message_entry.pack()

time_label = tk.Label(root, text='Введите время ожидания (например, '2 часа 39 минут'):')
time_label.pack()
time_entry = tk.Entry(root)
time_entry.pack()

submit_button = tk.Button(root, text='Отправить', command=on_submit)
submit_button.pack()

root.mainloop()


Не хотите добавить каких-то подробностей?

@Amgarak, я делал напоминалку через from win10toast import ToastNotifier, и хотел сделать так, чтобы я мог её с рабочего стола к примеру запустить и указать что и как нужно мне напомнить через tkinter меню. Но после запуска самого интерфейса(после компиляции), он тупо сворачивался(как я и хотел) и ничего не оповещает (уведомления не приходят). Пытался и чтобы не скрывалось, и чтобы чисто через терминал, после pyinstaller - уведомлений нет. Могу скинуть также код, может ошибся.

Приложите код, посмотрим.

@Amgarak в описании добавил.

@Amgarak есть идеи?
